# C drive reports 50GB "All in C:\", yet almost full at 75GB in Computer?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

I'm trying to install visual studio, which requires a bunch of disk space. I found the space easily by deleting 8.16GB of downloads in the User profile. Great! Clicked install but had to restart (I'd previously uninstalled a broken install).

Restarted the computer, with 12GB free on the C drive and...

[image]

Not enough space! No idea where it all went, so I was poking around, and it's exactly the same, the User profile has reduced by the 8GB, there's no new files I could find. The windows directory is still a shattering 33GB.

So I just selected everything and:

[image]

It comes to 50GB, I should have 30 free! Anyone know why this happened?

Cheers

EDIT: Worth noting, this is a work computer and I don't have great full admin rights and they won't like me installing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select every folder and look at the properties, Windows will enumerate all files and calculate the combined size.

However this process runs with you user account, so only files and folders you have access to will be enumerated. This will not take in account the folders you don't have at least read permissions on.

Even with full admin rights there's folder you cannot access by default.

On good example (an probably the bigger in size) is the "system volume information" folder.

If you run backup software that use Microsoft VSS technologies, there's volume snapshot that reside in this folder and that can use a lot of space.

Comment: Thanks, looks like there's not much I can do then. So frustrating that it only increased after I restarted after clearing enough space though!

Comment: I am not sure if the pagefile.sys and hibernation Files are counted as hidden or system files. pagefile.sys has always the size of your RAM but you can shrink in in advanced options if you have more than 4GB RAM in the system.